# How can I find where exception is thrown during a Minitest run in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, minitest, ruby-on-rails-2

My Ruby Minitest is failing with an error like this:

```
<"undefined method `Error' for Api:Module">
```

It is not actually a method that is missing, it is a class:

```
class Api::Error
```

This class is defined in lib/api/error.rb.

I tried adding this line to config/environment.rb in my rails 2 application:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/lib )
```

It does nothing. I do not know where or if RAILS_ROOT is defined (is it a standard rails 2 variable?), but I copied it from a commented out line in the existing source code.

How can I make sure the class is loaded or find where it is not included? The Api::Error subclasses are raised in many files, and I don't want to edit them all. Because the class cannot be found, the stacktrace does not list the place where the real raise occurs. Stepping through code using pry is not working, because as soon as I get to the "get" method in a Webservice mock, I can't step in.

Answer (score 0):

Once I found where the exception was being raised, I experimented.

This is how the code was originally, which caused the problem:

```
  raise Api::Error @p4_client
```

This is the change I made:

```
  raise Api::Error.new(@p4_client)
```

Explicitly calling the constructor with new rather than letting the raise logic in Ruby do it solved the problem.

This logic without the explicit call worked fine in 1.8.7, but fails in 1.9.3.
Everything is delegated through layers of Actionpack.